# C# Compare two strings with custom rules

Tags: c#, string

Is there a way to use string.Equals or string.Compare in way that two nulls or two empty strings return false or a number other than 0 respectively?

Use Case:

```
string.Equals(null, null) = false;
string.Equals("", string.empty) = false;

string.Compare(null, null) != 0;
string.Compare("", string.empty) != 0;
```

Comment: Can you explain why you would want to do such a thing?  Any comparison operation where things do not compare equal to themselves does not meet the requirements to be used in a sort, for instance.

Comment: @EricLippert I would want to do this because both null and empty values represent "unknown" values. I was just curious to know if there was a more elegant way than   If (!String.IsEmptyOrNull(val1) && !String.IsEmptyOrNull(val2) && String.Equals(val1, val2)) { // do stuff; }

Comment: Imagine for example that you have the rule that an empty string is larger than itself, and you are doing a sort on a list that contains two empty strings. The sort algorithm would be justified in swapping their positions in a loop, forever, because a larger item is *always* before a smaller item in this scenario.

Comment: Interesting thought. I'm not comparing but I see the negative consequences of that.

Comment: @EricLippert I don't think I understand this upvote/downvote thing... It seems so negative... If someone doesn't like the question, why downvote it? It was important to me... I am going to get to the point that I can't do anything except post questions because someone has decided to downvote me so much... :/

Comment: I did not downvote you, but the fact that you're asking how to do a very, very strange thing that breaks all kinds of rules without giving any context for why might make some people think the question is unclear. Also, you're asking what we call an "XY" question. You have some real problem to solve, you have a crazy idea about how to solve it, and you're asking how to make the crazy thing work. But the crazy thing is crazy.  Ask a question about the problem you really need to solve.

Comment: Now, I note that there *are* situations in C# where the rules of equality are bent or broken around nulls and NaNs.  NaN compares as unequal to itself, and is also not greater than itself and not less than itself. C# also has odd rules for comparison operators for nullable integers; it is possible that two of them can be *equal* but not *less than or equal* to each other, which defies logic. These situations are confusing and inconsistent and at least one former member of the language design team has some pretty serious reservations about these design choices.

Comment: @Maderas, your question was clear and you isolated the relevant code. But sometimes other workarounds come up once we know for what you wanted that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing a not before like:

```
!string.Equals(null, null)
```

Comment: I know but I was hoping there was a way to create a custom comparator to pass into this method. It was just a "creative" thought. Thanks.

Comment: @Clive, the values are passed as variables.